# Access Lucene IndexWriter from diffrent threads

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, lucene, jira

**Usage**

I'm using Lucene IndexWriter in a Plugin for Atlassian JIRA 6.4.1 to create my own index. The IndexWriter is used in a component which is created by the JIRA framework (JIRA uses the spring framework).

The component is used by different threads which write and read from the index. The IndexWriter is created on first use and all other threads use always the same instance of the IndexWriter.

The IndexWriter is only closed, after the Plugin is uninstalled or JIRA is shutdown (in between i just call commit, after a successful write) and there is my problem.

**Problem**

The component implements the org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean interface. In the method destroy (which is called on uninstall or shutdown) i want to close my IndexWriter, but the thread which closes the IndexWriter is different from the one who created the IndexWriter. So what happens is, that i get following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(ReentrantLock.java:151)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1261)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.unlock(ReentrantLock.java:457)
at com.atlassian.jira.util.LuceneDirectoryUtilsImpl$UtilConcurrentLock.release(LuceneDirectoryUtilsImpl.java:183)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.closeInternal(IndexWriter.java:1884)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.close(IndexWriter.java:1814)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.close(IndexWriter.java:1778)
```

This exception occurs, because the write lock generated is obtained in the Constructer of the IndexWriter is bound to another thread as the one who tries to close the IndexWriter.

As far as i know, I have no control over which thread generates my component and which one destroys my component, as this is handled by JIRA and the spring framework.

**My question is now, how can i correctly close my IndexWriter without running into this exception?**

Version: lucene-core-3.3.0-atlassian-1.jar (so it looks like a atlassian modified version)

Comment: Theoretically, IndexWriters are completeley thread safe. But the Exception is caused by ReentrantLock, not by Lucene. Can you somehow stick to the initial thread?

Comment: As I'm using the IndexWriter in a JIRA Plugin and the creation and destroy of the component is handled in the ComponentContainer in JIRA (spring-framework), I have not found a way yet, to stick to the thread.

A solution I'm currently thinking of is, that with every update/delete of the index I create a new Instance of the IndexWriter and close the IndexWriter after the action. But this is only a Workaround and a high cost operation.

Comment: Well, that's sad, as `ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease` explicitly checks if you are in the same thread that called `lock`...